# Terraform : How to use provider alias as an argument/parameter in a module?

Tags: terraform

I have aliased providers configured within my terraform modules for service account impersonnation purposes.

For the `dev` environment, in the root module , I have one that I dubbed `as_dev_admin` that enables the impersonnation of an admin account on the dev environment.

When I want to use this alias to create resources, for example, I do :

```
resource "google_folder" "some-folder-name" {
  provider     = google.as_dev_admin
...
}
```

But when I want to use it in an internal module, I do :

```
module "the-famous-module-instance" {
  providers = {
    google = google.as_dev_admin
  }
  source             = "../modules/the-famous-module"
}
```

Except I get this warning :

```
│ Warning: Reference to undefined provider
│
│   on main.tf line 3, in module "the-famous-module-instance":
│    3:     google = google.as_dev_admin
│
│ There is no explicit declaration for local provider name "google" in module.the-famous-module-instance, so Terraform is assuming you mean to pass a configuration for
│ "hashicorp/google".
│
│ If you also control the child module, add a required_providers entry named "google" with the source address "hashicorp/google".
╵
```

Is there some other syntax to use in order to do this correctly? How do I disable this warning if it's alright.

Comment: We need to see the `terraform` block in the module sourced at `../modules/the-famous-module`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, also I thought the `terraform` block is inherited from root module, but apparently not.

Comment: Provider configurations (`provider` blocks) _can_ be inherited from a parent module into a child, although the `providers` argument you are setting overrides that with explicit passing instead. Provider _requirements_ are never inherited, because each module must declare which providers it depends on; there can potentially be many providers called "google" in different namespaces (other than `hashicorp/`) and on different registries (other than `registry.terraform.io`) so Terraform uses these declarations to know what you mean by "google" in each module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `terraform` block must be included in the declared module sourced at `../modules/the-famous-module`. The most important nested block there for your issue would be the `required_providers`. This can be found in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings).

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

> also I thought the terraform block is inherited from root module, but apparently not

It can be partially passed to declared modules with a `providers` block, but otherwise no inheritance. You already are using this to pass an alias, and it can also pass provider configuration argument values, but not retrieval meta-argument values e.g. `version`, `source`, etc.